# Pass single-spa prop to i18n instantiation

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n, vue-props, single-spa

is there a way to pass a single-spa prop to a vue i18n instance, assigning it to the messages i18n prop.

I18n constructor:

```
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE,
  messages: {},
});
```

Vue single-spa instance:

```
const vueLifecycles = singleSpaVue({
  Vue,
  appOptions: {
    el: '#account',
    render() {
      return (
        <App
          eventBus={this.$data.eventBus}
          lang={this.$data.lang}
        ></App>
      );
    },
    i18n,
  },
});
```

Info: I dont have access to `lang` outside the render function.

Basically, I need the lang prop inside my i18n messages object. I tried already to return the lang and but it into the constructor, doesnt work.
I also tried to reinstantiate i18n/messages after `lang` is received, doesnt work either.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. It is only possible to alter the messages in your mounted vue instance with:

```
this.$i18n.setLocaleMessage = newLangObj
```